# Can you publish to a queue and write to the db within a Slick transaction, and still guarantee atomicity?

Tags: scala, transactions, rabbitmq, slick, atomic

I have a Slick server for which I'd like to use the `transactionally` keyword to perform a double-write of data to my database and a RabbitMQ message queue. My code looks something like this:

```
val a = (for {
    _ <- coffees.map(c => (c.name, c.supID, c.price)) += ("Colombian_Decaf", 101, 8.99)
    ch.txSelect()
    ch.basicPublish("SELL " + c.name, QUEUE_NAME, MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC, "nop".getBytes())
    ch.txCommit()
} yield ()).transactionally
```

My question is: Is it possible for the queue publish action to commit successfully, but have the DB insert fail? In this case, my system would be in an inconsistent state, as I would only want the message to be published to the queue if the value was successfully inserted into the database, and vice versa.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you the answer is that you can't easily guarantee consistency for such a system. What you want is [distributed transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction) and they are fundamentally hard. To see why this is so you can make the following thought experiment: what happens if your computer blows up (or less radically gets cut of electricity) at the most unfortunate moment? For this code one of such bad moments is exactly after the line `ch.txCommit()` is fully executed (so it is before the outer DB transaction is committed as well). Fundamentally there is nothing you can do about such scenario unless somehow these two concurrent transactions a aware of each other. Unfortunately I don't know about any distributed transaction coordinators to cover both traditional SQL DBs and RabbitMQ. So your choices are:

1. Give up and do nothing (and develop some procedure to recover after disastrous events afterward in a manual mode)
2. Implement some distributed transaction algorithm such as [2-phase commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) yourself. This most probably requires some re-design and a complicated implementation.
3. Re-design your system to use some form of [eventual consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). This probably requires a bigger re-design but still might be easier to implement than #2.

Comment: Thanks! I was originally thinking it might be okay, because for this particular system of 2 nodes, the 2-phase commit might look like:

`db pre-commit; mq pre-commit; mq commit; db commit`

OR

`db pre-commit, mq pre-commit; mq abort; db abort`

which is what we are doing here. But I guess the thing that I'm missing would be the recovery in case of node failure, which is technically implemented by two-phase commit implementations.

Comment: @BobRisky, 1. depending on your circumstances plan #1 (i.e. hope that it will work as is) might be or not be still OK for you. 2. Yes, for distribution transactions to really work you need some entity (coordinator) that guarantees delivery of second-phase commit/abort message to all the participants even in case of that participant failure or its own failure. This is actually not that trivial to achieve. Typically it means the coordinator needs its own [WAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging) to store all transactions and all commit/abort decisions before sending messages.

Comment: Makes sense. I think I will probably try to go for a different approach, then, as the 2-phase commit seems excessively complicated for my use case. Who knew that using 2 separate databases would be so complicated? :P Well, I guess I know now. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @BobRisky, It also means that the coordinator needs a means of guaranteed at least once delivery of the messages to all nodes which is kind of the whole purpose of a thing like RabbitMQ. Probably the simplest way to achieve consistency similar to what you want is to make RabbitMQ the main source of data and have two consumers: your original one and another one that just saves the data to the DB. I'm not RabbitMQ specialist but looking into the features list ([particularly acknowledgement](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html)) it looks like you can do it that way.